# Estimating missing values within a data - Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a 525600x1 matrix containing too many numbers. This data has lots of NaN values in it. Is there any method in matlab so I can accurately estimate the NaN values?

Thanks

George

Comment: do you mean interpolate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you are asking for an interpolation.

Assume some 1D-Data with gaps:

```
x=[1:100]*pi
x(randi(3,100,1)==3)=nan
```

If you want to interpolate, you have data at these indices `find(~isnan(x))`, the non nan values are `x(~isnan(x))` and you want data for all indices in your matrix `1:numel(x)`

```
x_interp=interp1(find(~isnan(x)),x(~isnan(x)),1:numel(x))
```

Comment: you might wanna specify to enable extrapolation in case the NaN values appear at the edges (beginning or end the vector): `interp1(..., 'linear', 'extrap')`